# Kafka Connect JDBC Sink Connector giving WorkerSinkTask ERROR

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using Jdbc Sink Connector with following configs:

```
curl -s -X POST http://********:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
"name":"mysql-sensor-sink-connector-02",
"config": {
"tasks.max":"2",
"batch.size":"1000",
"batch.max.rows":"1000",
"poll.interval.ms":"500",
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
"connection.url":"jdbc:mysql://**********:3306/device_details",    
"table.name.format":"tb_sensordata",
"topics":"sensor_data_topic",
"connection.user":"*******",
"connection.password":"********",
"insert.mode":"insert",
"auto.create":"true",
"auto.evolve":"true",
"pk.mode":"record_value",
"pk.fields":"packetid",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",  
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable":"false"
}
}' | jq '.'
```

The ERROR I am getting is this:

```
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,444] INFO ProducerConfig values:
        acks = all
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = [cpnode.local.lan:9092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = confluent.monitoring.interceptor.connector-consumer-mysql-sensor-sink-connector-03-1
        compression.type = lz4
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
        enable.idempotence = false
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
        linger.ms = 500
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
        max.request.size = 10485760
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 10
        retry.backoff.ms = 500
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig:347)
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,457] INFO Kafka version: 5.4.0-ce (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:117)
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,457] INFO Kafka commitId: ca78a82127cbef3a (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:118)
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,458] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1587183136457 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:119)
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,458] INFO interceptor=confluent.monitoring.interceptor.connector-consumer-mysql-sensor-sink-connector-03-1 created for client_id=connector-consumer-mysql-sensor-sink-connector-03-1 client_type=CONSUMER session= cluster=dy7maqKlQBysl4HTbJuIEQ group=connect-mysql-sensor-sink-connector-03 (io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringInterceptor:153)
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,470] INFO Attempting to open connection #1 to MySql (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:87)
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,602] INFO JdbcDbWriter Connected (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter:49)
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,765] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=mysql-sensor-sink-connector-03-1} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:559)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.flush(BufferedRecords.java:174)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:72)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:539)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,766] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=mysql-sensor-sink-connector-03-1} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:561)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.flush(BufferedRecords.java:174)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:72)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:539)
        ... 10 more
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,766] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=mysql-sensor-sink-connector-03-1} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:180)
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,766] INFO Stopping task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:105)
[2020-04-18 09:42:16,767] INFO Closing connection #1 to MySql (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:113)
```

The data in topic is in JSON format **without** schema.

When running the console consumer I am able to see the data as follows:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server *********:9092 --topic sensor_data_topic --from-beginning | jq '.'
{
  "packetid": 1501,
  "macaddress": "F8-27-B9-C7-AB-99",
  "readingtypeid": "temperature",
  "readingvalue": 70.1,
  "setpoint": 77.2,
  "threshold": 7,
  "readingtime": "2019-05-20 02:46:30",
  "logtime": "2019-09-01 19:32:06"
}
{
  "packetid": 1502,
  "macaddress": "2B-6A-C1-45-86-ED",
  "readingtypeid": "temperature",
  "readingvalue": 65.21,
  "setpoint": 77.06,
  "threshold": 7,
  "readingtime": "2019-05-17 03:39:18",
  "logtime": "2020-04-05 06:37:45"
}
```

The mysql table is as follows:

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| packetid        | bigint      | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                   |
| macaddress      | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| readingtypeid   | bigint      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| readingvalue    | float       | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| setpoint        | float       | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| threshold       | float       | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| lastupdatedtime | timestamp   | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| logtime         | timestamp   | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Can anyone please help me sink my data in MySql.
Thanks in advance.

PS:
The version I am using is:
**Confluent Platform 5.4.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use sink connector then you must define schemas. This can be achieve either using Avro and Schema Registry or JSON with schemas.

---

If you want to stick to `JsonConverter`, just make sure schemas are enabled:

```
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",  
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "true"
```

Comment: The original topic doesn't have a schema.

I tried to do the **true** value, getting this error:


`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.`

Comment: @HasnainMotagamwala You might have to replay your data using a JSON schema this time. Once you do it, it will work as expected. Also make sure to remove the older messages which don't come with a schema. As I mentioned, for JDBC sink connector, you must use schemas.

Comment: Just read the same on apache confluence page. **KIP-301: Schema Inferencing for JsonConverter**.
@Giorgosmyrianthous Thank a lot.....was a big help....